# What was used to create the metal effect makeup in the Terminator robots?

Tags: effects, terminator-series, make-up, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles season 1 & 2 we can see Terminator robots walking with damages in their body parts. How do the make-up artists in the TV series make these metal effects on human actors and actresses. Do these make-up artists have some kind of liquid that looks like metal?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In the TV show? Possibly green paint. [TERMINATOR GENISYS: Making the Terminator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bB8KO6N0Jx0)

Comment: @Mazura I know that's about the film, but still seems to be a good start for a plausible answer, if fleshed out beyond a mere YouTube link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually for something like this, they use Silicone appliances, that are painted.
(Rarely) hard plastic pieces, that are placed on an actors body, are used.

Some ways to get that chrome looks are:

- vacuum Metalising
- silver spray painting (yes they really do it)
- or Alumaluster (http://www.imperialsurfacetechnologies.com/ist-alumaluster.html)

One has to keep in mind, that this Method(Makeup) is only additive.
They use different Methods to subtract parts.

Also, on Terminator, they use fake heads or sometimes even rebuild the whole person, for a shot. Of course, they use CGI as well.

Good effects usually are a mix of various practical and digital effects.